# Displaying the Popup box generated by Greybox on page load(onLoad)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload, greybox

I have the following html code :

```
<a href="http://google.com/" title="Google" rel="gb_page_center[500, 500]">Launch</a>
```

It launches a popup generated with GREYBOX when I click on LAUNCH. but now I want this to happen automatically every time the website is opened! How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <body>

    <script>
        AJS.AEV(window, 'load', function() {
          GB_show("Hello world", "http://google.com");
     });
    </script>
```

The AJS library used by greybox offers it's own pageload call

Comment: Thanx a lot Rajat for ur answer, But i am a noob :P Hardly know anything. Please telme how to use this code ! where shall i add this ?

Comment: Yeah man !! it worked out !! Thnx a ton :):) Thnku very much :) :)